# How to push notification in ionic2 app?

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm newbie in ionic2 framework. Please suggest suitable plugin or solution to develop push notification from server in ionic2 application.

Thanks,
DSCanon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) which is completely free and then you can follow [these steps](http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-setup-push-notifications-for-android-with-onesignal-17) to add it to your `Ionic2` application.

After setting everything up like it's explained in that post, you would need to install the `oneSignal cordova plugin`

`cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin`

Then, add the following code to your app.ts so that it runs on startup:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
  let appId = "CHANGE ME";
  let googleProjectNumber = "CHANGE ME";
  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal.init(appId, {googleProjectNumber: googleProjectNumber}, notificationOpenedCallback);

  // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
  window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
}, false);
```

Note: substitute in your

- appId from OneSignal
- googleProjectNumber

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sebaferreras

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Push* from Ionic2 Native `import {Push} from 'ionic-native';`

[Here](http://nishanthkabra.com/ionic2push.html) you can find more information about setting up your app.

Comment: Thank you very much, @muetzerich

Answer (score 0):

Please use the ionic-cloud-angular released by the Ionic team for utilising their services like Auth, push, deploy etc., in Ionic 2 apps.

You can refer here for Push Notifications - http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-push-notifications/

It gives detailed and simple instructions on how to achieve this.

Hope this helped you. Thanks.